# Saving Checkmarks on TableView loaded from Firebase Database Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So im populating a table View from firebase database. I am able to add and remove check marks. But i can't seem to figure out how to save it. Since the tableView reloads the data every time the view appears.

here is my view controller

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase

class guestListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var guestListTableView: UITableView!



var guestListDBRef : DatabaseReference!
var guestListText = [AdminTextModel]()

var keyArray : [String] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guestListDBRef = Database.database().reference().child("RSVP")
    guestListDBRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
        for guestListLabel in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let guestListTextObject = guestListLabel.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let name = guestListTextObject?["name"]
            let date = guestListTextObject?["date"]
            let guestListTextLabels = AdminTextModel(name: name as! String?, date: date as! String?)
            self.guestListText.append(guestListTextLabels)
            self.guestListTableView.rowHeight = 45
            self.guestListTableView.reloadData()
            self.getKeys()

            }
        }
    })


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return guestListText.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let guestListTextCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guestList") as! guestListTableViewCell
    let text: AdminTextModel
    text = guestListText[indexPath.row]
    guestListTextCell.guestListNameLabel.text = text.name
    guestListTextCell.guestListDateLabel.text = text.date
    return guestListTextCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    } else {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

My AdminTextModel

```
import Foundation

class AdminTextModel {
var name: String?
var date: String?
init(name: String?, date: String?) {

    self.name = name
    self.date = date
   }
}
```

And my TableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class guestListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var guestListDateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var guestListNameLabel: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Let me know if you have any input!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiKJL.p)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPkIh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5Vo1.png)ng

Comment: you can handle this in 2 ways either maintaining an Array off-line in code or by making a check in firebase DB

Comment: There are many bad practices in your code. 1. Class names should start with **Capital** letter. 2. You should never call the delegate methods that you didn't define by yourself. 3. Practically your `var guestListDBRef` is never going to be mutated, so make this a constant with `let`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your model to this

> ```
> class AdminTextModel {
>     var name: String?
>     var date: String?
>     var isChecked: Bool?
>     init(name: String?, date: String?, isChecked: Bool?) {
>
>         self.name = name
>         self.date = date
>         self.isChecked = isChecked
>
>        }
>     }
> ```

2. The isChecked property should also be saved in your firebase database
3. Now fetch the data and set the checkmark to true or false based on the isChecked property.
4. This will retain the checkmark even after reloading the screen

Answer (score 0):

As per Moaz Khan change model class and also need to change in cellForRowAt with below code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let guestListTextCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guestList") as! guestListTableViewCell
    let text: AdminTextModel
    text = guestListText[indexPath.row]
    guestListTextCell.guestListNameLabel.text = text.name
    guestListTextCell.guestListDateLabel.text = text.date

    if text.isChecked {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    return guestListTextCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let isChecked = !self.guestListText[indexPath.row].isChecked
    let key = self.guestListText[indexPath.row].key
    Checkedservice.checkuncheck(key: key, isChecked: isChecked) { (seccess) in
        guard seccess else { return }
        self.guestListText[indexPath.section].isChecked = isChecked
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}
```

**Check mark service for firebase**

```
struct Checkedservice {
    static func checkuncheck(key: String, isChecked: Bool, success: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        let onlinesRef = Database.database().reference().child("RSVP").child(key).child("isChecked")
        onlinesRef.setValue(isChecked) {(error, _ ) in

            if let error = error {
                assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
                success(false)
            }
            success(true)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update model class**

```
class AdminTextModel {
    var key: String?
    var name: String?
    var date: String?
    var isChecked: Bool?
    init(key: String?, name: String?, date: String?, isChecked: Bool?) {
        self.key = key
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
        self.isChecked = isChecked

       }
    }
```

Comment: child("RSVP").child("yourchild name") is where i believe i'm having an issue. My child is created with childByAutoID.

Comment: thank you! i just keep getting a nil value for key every time I click to check

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!, I went ahead and implemented that iParesh, but i think my issue lies here. Since im using childByAutoID.

```
let onlinesRef = Database.database().reference().child("RSVP").child("yourchild name")
```

[image: this is the issue i'm having]